# .NET (C# or VB) - How to make Windows understand the system is not idle while playing sound

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I have a .NET app that plays sound for an extended period of time (multiple minutes) using a circular buffer. While the app is playing sound, its resource utilization is really low (zero disk use, less than 2% CPU, 30 MB memory) which is great! BUT it seems that while the app is playing sound Windows thinks the system is idle so it tends to spin up lots of background services which on low-end / budget systems (celeron CPU) can cause interruption of sound at times when the background services chew up all the system resources.

My question...Is there a way that I can make Windows understand that the system is NOT idle while my app is playing sound? Note that while the app is playing sound the user does NOT need to touch anything (keyboard, mouse, etc) which would of course cue the system that it is not idle. I have already tried messing with thread priority making it "Above Normal" or "High" but windows background services still misbehaved as described above.

Thanks!

Comment: You might be looking for the [`SetThreadExecutionState` function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373208(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: `BUT it seems that while the app is playing sound Windows thinks the system is idle so it tends to spin up lots of background services` How did you come to that conclusion?

Comment: mjwills - I have Task Manager open and visible and monitor the resources/services as my app plays sound vs when I have keyboard or mouse input in my app.

Comment: Ahmed - SetThreadExecutionState looks promising. I will give it a whirl. Thanks!

Comment: I added some code using SetThreadExecutionState as suggested and tested. It appears to work well and keep the background services in check. Thanks so much!!